# @PublishEvent, ajax and passing data

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, tapestry

I try to use [@PublishEvent](http://tapestry.apache.org/ajax-and-zones.html#AjaxandZones-Invokingserver-sideeventhandlermethodsfromJavaScript) and new possibility to create a server-side event handler. However, in the example that is attached to the link above, there is no data passing from JS to Server. 
Looking in [docks](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/coffeescript/ajax.html) revealed that there is a "data" option to pass data (at least for now, this is my interpretation). However, I can't get it working, only "empty" method handler is working.

My code looks like this:

JS:

```
ajax('action',{
      element: $(element),
      data: {
         test:'test'
      },
      success: function(response) {
         console.log(response);
      }
}
```

JAVA:

```
@OnEvent("action")
    @PublishEvent
    public void action(JSONObject test)
    {
      //Code to handle execution
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, sometimes the solution is simpler than expected.

Appropriate handler class should look like this:

```
@OnEvent("action")
@PublishEvent
public void action(@RequestParameter("test") String test)
{
  //Code to handle execution
}
```